# AssertJ's SoftAssertions.assertSoftly is hanging my test at 892 assertions

Tags: serenity-bdd, assertj

Im doing a database comparison test using serenity-bdd.  I am currently testing 892 records.  All 892 failed as expected.

AssertJ's SoftAssertions.assertSoftly appears to have ran through all 892 successfully.

But then it hangs the test and wont complete the Serenity report.

Im assuming it is overwhelmed because all 892 failed, so it had to process all 892.

But we are early in our development so this is going to happen a lot.

Does anyone know what the limits of SoftAssertions is.  How high can I batch my assertions without it hanging my test

Comment: I'm not sure if this type of metric has ever been analyzed. What test framework are you using? This would help understand the execution path in AssertJ internals.

Comment: Since you are targeting a database, have you considered https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-db? There is no support for soft assertions, but this could be circumvented with different test methods if the target is purely a comparison of values.

Comment: Thank You @StefanoCordio - yes...this may be an issue with SerenityReporter and not with AssertJ.  I will check out assertj-db.  Thank You